# Shell scripting: die on any error

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Suppose a shell script (/bin/sh or /bin/bash) contained several commands.  How can I cleanly make the script terminate if any of the commands has a failing exit status?  Obviously, one can use if blocks and/or callbacks, but is there a cleaner, more concise way?  Using && is not really an option either, because the commands can be long, or the script could have non-trivial things like loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With standard `sh` and `bash`, you can

```
set -e
```

It will

```
$ help set
...
        -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

It also works (from what I could gather) with `zsh`. It also should work for any Bourne shell descendant.

With `csh`/`tcsh`, you have to launch your script with `#!/bin/csh -e`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I want.  I should sharpen my Google fu, I guess... :)

Comment: Note that commands in conditionals can fail without causing the script to exit - which is crucial.  For example: if grep something /some/where; then : it was found; else : it was not found; fi works fine, regardless of whether something is found in /some/where.

Comment: You say "standard sh".  Does this mean that it is POSIX?  Edit:  I've looked it up and it is POSIX:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html

Answer (score 25):

May be you could use:

```
$ <any_command> || exit 1
```

Comment: This pattern is useful for **selectively exiting on failure of individual commands** and also **if you want to print a custom error message** first.
To do the latter, use something like `<any_command> || eval 'echo "Please ensure ..." 1>&2; exit 1'`
NOTE: The `eval` trick is necessary to group the `echo` and `exit` commands together without creating a _sub_-shell; use of a sub-shell (as would happen if you used parentheses) would render the `exit` ineffective.

Comment: Live and learn: Bash has a command-grouping feature, so there's no need for the `eval` trick I mentioned. Instead, use `<any_command> || { echo "Please ensure ..." 1>&2; exit; }` (note the required `;` before the closing `}`).

Answer (score 2):

You can check $? to see what the most recent exit code is..

e.g

```
#!/bin/sh
# A Tidier approach

check_errs()
{
  # Function. Parameter 1 is the return code
  # Para. 2 is text to display on failure.
  if [ "${1}" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "ERROR # ${1} : ${2}"
    # as a bonus, make our script exit with the right error code.
    exit ${1}
  fi
}

### main script starts here ###

grep "^${1}:" /etc/passwd > /dev/null 2>&1
check_errs $? "User ${1} not found in /etc/passwd"
USERNAME=`grep "^${1}:" /etc/passwd|cut -d":" -f1`
check_errs $? "Cut returned an error"
echo "USERNAME: $USERNAME"
check_errs $? "echo returned an error - very strange!"
```

Comment: -1: This is an all-too frequent antipattern. @Barun's solution is simpler and more idiomatic.

Comment: same script as above, but as a tidier "tidier approach" (all on one line):  foo=$(grep "^${1}" /etc/passwd) && foo=$(echo "$foo" | cut -d: -f1) && echo ok || echo not_ok
(nb: if using bash, and not limited to sh, one can get the exit status of any part of a pipeline, which simplifies the grep/cut logic.)

Comment: +1: This allows for proper, contextual error handling in the script without the complication of subshells.