# How would you improve this shell script to check for errors before executing each task?

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, scripting

I am a beginner.

Here is a shell script I created that resides on a production server. The goal is to refresh my production Drupal content with that found on a staging/test server.

How it works:
It shells into a test/staging server, does a mysqldump of my Drupal content database, then SCPs that dump over to a temporary folder in Production. From there, it takes a backup of the current Production Drupal content database (again via mysqldump) and then refreshes the Production content database with the dump from the staging server.

My question:
While I know how to write a script to execute the commands, I am unclear on how to implement error checking (for example, checking a return code I guess?) before the next command executes.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Name: drupal_dump.sh
# Developer: Michael Paul
# Created: 2014-03-21
# Last updated: 2014-04-28
# Description: 
#   1. Remotes into Test server, runs a script to take a dump of Drupal content DB.
#   2. Copies (scp) that dump to Prod
#   3. Takes backup of current prod Drupal content DB
#   4. Overwrites current prod Drupal content DB with the one from Test
#
#   If needed, issue the following command to restore the production backup:
#       mysql -p -u root myDrupalDatabase < path/to/backupfile.sql

REMOTEHOST=xx.xxx.xx.xxx
REMOTEUSER=myRemoteUsername
DUMPDIR=~/sqldumps
DESTDIR=~/incoming
BACKUPSDIR=~/backups
LOGSDIR=~/logs

TIMESTAMP="`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`"
DUMPFILE="mysqldump_stage_${TIMESTAMP}.sql"
PRODBACKUPFILE="mysqldump_prod_${TIMESTAMP}.sql"

# Remote into Test server, backup Drupal database
echo "Creating dump file on Test server..."
ssh -i ~/.ssh/myRemoteServer.pem $REMOTEUSER@$REMOTEHOST "mysqldump --routines -u root --password= myDrupalDatabase > $DUMPDIR/$DUMPFILE && exit"
echo "Dump file created at $DUMPDIR/$DUMPFILE"

# Copy that dump to Prod
echo "Copying Test dump file to $DESTDIR on Prod..."
scp -i ~/.ssh/myRemoteServer.pem $REMOTEUSER@$REMOTEHOST:$DUMPDIR/$DUMPFILE $DESTDIR
echo "File has been copied to $DESTDIR/$DUMPFILE on Prod."

# Backup current Prod Drupal content DB
echo "Backing up current Production Drupal content database..."
mysqldump --routines -u root --password=  myDrupalDatabase > $BACKUPSDIR/$PRODBACKUPFILE
echo "File backed up as $BACKUPSDIR/$PRODBACKUPFILE"

# Overwrite current Prod Drupal content DB with that taken from Test
echo "Updating Production database with content from Test..."
mysql -p -u root --password= myDrupalDatabase < $DESTDIR/$DUMPFILE
echo "Update complete."
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1222559/21755

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 2):

The return code for the last command is stored in the variable `$?`. Success is defined as `0`, anything else is program-dependant.

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/myRemoteServer.pem $REMOTEUSER@$REMOTEHOST:$DUMPDIR/$DUMPFILE $DESTDIR
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Some sort of error message."
  exit 1
fi
```

You can also skip the `[`/`test` utility and invoke the command directly in the `if` statement like so:

```
if grep -q foo bar.txt; then
  echo "found foo!"
else
  echo "no foo!"
  exit 1
fi
```